# Suggestions for Security Design for Access Control List in database?

Tags: c#, database, security, database-design, access-control

I have users for my application with access control list (these are both tables/schema/objects). Currently these are read from the database, Boolean values are used to indicate what they can view/manipulate. However, anyone can still go to the database and change the data. Can someone offer some suggestion on what kind of things I can do? I hope I am clear we have users (uname + pass) and acl (empui_access, empdat_manipulate). Any kinda security solutions via code etc...

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? Are there a lot of different rights? A lot of users? Different access levels for each right?

Comment: no worries of database i could use any this is related to coding design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
table users
username: string
password_hash: hex
acl: bit array
```

username is the username, password_hash is the hash of the password, with a grain of salt. It's wrong to store a plain password, but you already knew that, didn't you?

ACL is declared as a string but used as a bit array. 
Each bit represents a certain permission. 1 means the user has the permission, 0 means he doesn't. To check for a certain bit's value, you do a bit-wise AND on the acl. If the result is non-zero, access is granted. If the result is zero, access is denied.

For example:

```
// permission to read employee data
public const long READ_EMPL_DATA = 0x01

...
{
    User user = database.GetSomeUser();
    // test for READ_EMPL_DATA permission
    if (0 != (user.ACL & READ_EMPL_DATA)) {
        // access granted
    } else {
        // access denied
    }
    // give READ_EMPL_DATA permission
    if (0 != (user.ACL & READ_EMPL_DATA))
        user.ACL = user.ACL & READ_EMPL_DATA
}
```

To add group support, add a couple tables.

```
table group
groupname: string
acl: bit array

table user_group
user_id: id
group_id: id
```

And in addition to testing for the user-level permission, test the groups to which the user belongs. Of course, you'll write some helper functions, maybe a stored procedure.

I hope this got you started. If not, I can give you a more descriptive example, or more actual code, or other help.

Comment: can't someone modify you bit array (i havent used it before) from the db and it can change the user rights?

Comment: That's another type of problem. Yes, someone with the correct permissions could modify that value. But then again, that person could also change the password. It's about securing your database, and SQL Server already has a solution for that. For instance, you could give the guest user read permissions on our 3 tables, but without write permissions, they can't make changes.

Comment: this acl is not related with db,this is a business requirement

Answer (score -1):

This is specific to PostgreSQL, but you can probably get some good ideas from [Veil](http://veil.projects.postgresql.org/curdocs/index.html).